# Are there quick time events in Resident Evil 7?

Tags: resident-evil-7

Should I expect to hammer the attack key and follow on-screen button prompts as in RE 4-6, and how often?

Comment: [This](http://www.polygon.com/2016/6/24/12027358/resident-evil-7-quick-time-events-nope) and [this](https://www.destructoid.com/capcom-promises-there-are-no-quick-time-events-in-resident-evil-7-371065.phtml) might be of interest. I think calling the prompts in RE7 QTEs is not accurate, they are more tutorials on defending and attacking in my opinion

Answer (score 6):

QTEs are pretty rare. The only one I really remember was early in the game to fend off an attack from someone before you even actually have a weapon.

Comment: One in the garage too. But they are few and far between, and it's even debatable if they are really QTEs anyway. You certainly don't need to 'hammer' anything. I even wonder if you can actually fail them? It's definitely not difficult to do them that's for sure

Comment: @musefan: You have to push buttons repeatably when you're being attacked for the first time. And you can certainly fail that QTE.

Comment: Have you completed the game?

Comment: Yes, I've completed the game on normal and about halfway on Madhouse

Comment: @user598527: Actually, pretty sure you can just hold the button on that first one. And it's just one button, not *buttons*. Regardless, my point was, they are not difficult enough to worry about. If you are failing them, it might just be worth giving up on the game now (I have also completed it, in case that question was directed at me)

Comment: I don't remember any QTE-type stuff in the garage. Just watched a replay of that on Youtube and didn't see it then either. Is it maybe optional?

Comment: @Sterno: I may be remembering incorrectly, but I originally through it prompts you to pull the trigger at the end. On my second playthrough I pressed it as soon as I could so didn't see a prompt. Either you need to wait for it, *or* I am mistaken. Can't say for sure... until playthough 3 that is where I will test

Comment: @musefan: Completed the garage boss fight, no QTEs encountered.

Comment: @user598527: And how long did you wait before pulling the trigger?

Comment: @musefan: I can't currently even remember any context-sensitive part in the fight...?

Comment: @user598527: No worries, I don't want to say specifically as it's a bit of a spoiler. I will get around to confirming it eventually and can update once I do

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to spam any buttons, but you do have to hold one button near the start of the game, and you'll never really need to use that action again. However you may include timing the block button after pretty much every attack, as this will help in the dlc as well where you can black attacks.
/